# Syntax-highlighting for SQL strings in Python code

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm taking my first steps in SQLite3 in Python using VSCode. My problem is when I use a SQL command there isn't any syntax highlighting.

[image]

Is there any way to get the syntax highlighting?

Comment: Your editor is using Python syntax highligthing, since you're writting Python. But from the Python point of view the SQL command is just a string, not different from "hello world" and the like. You won't get any syntax highligh within that (VSCode has no way to know that the string is actually a SQL command). Not coindicentally, this happens in all languages and editors.

Comment: This is supported in the pycharm editor by default. Will highlight any SQL strings and if you have a database connected to the editor, it will even give you autocomplete suggestions

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
Thank you for your answer, but I've found one way: using Sublime Text.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77P94.png)

Answer (score 1):

It Seems that the SQL Command is just a String and all Editors Work this way and doesn't recognise code inside a String.
Anyways found some VS-CODE Extensions that might be of help,

[Python String SQL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ptweir.python-string-sql)
[Highlight String Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iuyoy.highlight-string-code#:%7E:text=Insert%20sign%20pair%20%2D%2Dbeginsql,with%20%3B%20will%20be%20highlighted%20automatically.)